# Appending multiple objects to an element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to append the same object multiple times to the same area, but its not working.

```
 $("div").each(function(){
   var $input = $("<input type=text/>").css("display","none");
   $(this).append($input).append($input);  // <--this only shows 1 box
 }
```

I tried `$(this).append($input + $input);`, but it shows `[object Object]` twice instead. Suggestions?

Comment: $(this).append($input.clone()).append($input.clone())

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/append/: _“If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned)”_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about

```
var $input = $(document.createElement('input')).attr('type','text').css({display:'none'});
$(this).append($input.clone()).append($input.clone())
```

Comment: works fine, but don't see why you need `.clone()` on both appends

Comment: you need to use .clone() for second .append(). When you appending element to container, the element disapears from the previous location. Dom element must have only one parent.

Answer (score -1):

by doing `$input + $input` they both get their `.toString()` methods ran so you're basically running `.append("[object Object][object Object]")`

and by doing `.append($input).append($input);` you are attempting to append the same `DOM Element` twice in the same containing element, which is impossible because only one instance will ever exist. The solution is to clone the DOM Element, you can do this in jQuery by `.clone()` and in vanilla javascript by `.cloneNode()`.

you can try

```
$("div").each(function(){
    var $input = $("<input type=text/>").css("display","none");

    $(this)
        .append($input) // use the original element
        .append($input.clone()); // clone the original element
}
```

Comment: @ZeeTee: because this is the answer.

Comment: @DavidKnipe i did provide a suggestion

Comment: @ZeeTee i also added a explanation to why your other attempt didn't work